# Sonata Admin display knp translatable translation in sonata_type_collection

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Utilising knp translatable doctrine extension with sonata admin.

When you have a translated entity with a collection of entities that are also translated, is it possible to get the translated item to appear in sonata_type_collection?

: e.g. `CategoryEntity` has a oneToMany association with `ArticleEntity`, both have translation tables configured. In the `CategoryAdmin`, a property `articles` with type `sonata_type_collection` is defined, however no values appear (The translations are definitely working otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this situation and end up with this solution,
Simply just add **mergeNewTranslations()** on prePersist() and preUpdate()
The sample code look like,

```
<?php

namespace Website\CategoryBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;


class CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin 
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {

        ...

        $formMapper
        ->with('config.label_category', ['class' => 'col-md-12'])
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                    'label' => 'config.label_name'
                ]
            )
        ->end()

        ->with('config.label_article', ['class' => 'col-md-12'])
            ->add('articles', CollectionType::class,
                    [
                        'label' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                    ],
                    [
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'table',
                        'sortable' => 'position',
                    ]
                )
        ->end()
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function prePersist($obj)
    {
        foreach ($obj->getArticles() as $article) {
            // $article->translate();
            $article->mergeNewTranslations(); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function preUpdate($obj)
    {
         foreach ($obj->getArticles() as $article) {
            // $article->translate();
            $article->mergeNewTranslations(); 
        }
    }

}
```